# Is this method correct to calculate the magnitude of the Fourier transform for a specific frequency?

Tags: waves

$$g(f)=g(t)e^{-2 \pi i f t}$$

For a frequency of 5 Hz.
To calculate the real component, $2 \pi f t = 2 * 3.14 * 5 * 1$ (setting time to one) $= 31.4$, so

$$e^{2πft} = 4,333,579,136,8684 \, .$$

Would that be a correct method?
Otherwise what would be the correct way to calculate it?
And what are the conditions that would allow setting time to 1?

Comment: There's an $i$ missing from the exponent in the second equation.

Comment: Would it be correct to remove the i if i want to calculate the real component ?

Comment: No, it would not be correct. For one thing, the real part of $e^{2\pi ift}$ is $\cos{2\pi ift}$. See [Euler’s Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that is not the correct way, and the correct way has nothing to do with setting the time to 1.

If you have a periodic function $g(t)$ with period $T$, then the Fourier transform for that function will only have nonzero values at discrete frequencies $n/T$ for integer $n$. The values of the Fourier transform at those points $c_n$ can be obtained using the following:

$$c_n=\frac{1}{T}\int_0^Tg(t)e^{-2\pi i(n/T)t}dt$$

The general Fourier transform for a not-necessarily-periodic function $g(t)$ is given by:

$$g(f)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(t)e^{-2\pi ift}dt$$

These two formulations are not necessarily compatible, as there are many different conventions for defining the Fourier transform.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering. Could you please let me know ,how would i solve that function then for a specific frequency ?Thank you

Comment: @Garhy Pick a particular value for $f$, and integrate.

Comment: Ah ,ok. Thank you.

Comment: It might be better to explain that for periodic $g$, the integral written here gives the Fourier series coefficients, which are defined only for $f = n / T$ where $n$ is an integer.

Comment: and what would n be representing in that case ?

Comment: @DanielSank Edited to fix.

Comment: @Garhy The Fourier transform of a periodic function only has nonzero values at points that are integer multiples of a fundamental frequency $1/T$. In other words, $n$ is some integer, representing the $n$th Fourier component.

Comment: @probably_someone thank you for the further clarifications ,i will process it a bit and i will ask again if i have more questions. Thank you so much